# Track CSS modifications on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-devtools

I saw that FireBug can track CSS changes with its plugin FireDiff, but I have a CSS bug that only occurs on Google Chrome. So I would like to know if something similar exists for this browser.

Or maybe a JS layer that would intercept any `.style` change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of the [Breakpoints on DOM Mutation Events](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html#dom) in Google Chrome.

The Google I/O 2011 [Video on Chrome Dev Tools Reloaded](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/chrome-dev-tools-reloaded.html) goes into some depth.